# Download the .exe file instead of .htm file

Tags: dropbox

My website has an option of downloading a .exe file. I uploaded this .exe file in dropbox and use the shared link in my website for the users to download the file.

> I use href in my index.php page to create a link to that file:

```
<a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/........./File.exe?dl=0" download="File">
```

But when users click that link in my website it downloads the .htm file. The users need to click this .htm file again which then leads to the download of the .exe file. At times users also get the error "There was an error downloading your file." while downloading the file from dropbox. I would like to know how to get the link to download the .exe file directly. Thanks!!!

Comment: Why don't you host the file instead of having it on Dropbox?

Comment: try `dl=1`, https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use  `?d1=0` at the end of your file path it will show the file in a preview page. Try changing it to `?dl=1`to force the download.

https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download